# angular updated http promise methods not working where legacy ones do

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to learn the mean stack from the book 'Getting MEAN' which is a little old now, so I'm using more up to date code where applicable.  I have just run across an issue that I can't quite solve myself.  There is a controller in the book (which uses an older version of angular) written as

```js
var locationListCtrl = function ($scope, loc8rData) {
  loc8rData
    .success(function (data) {
      $scope.data = { locations: data };
    })
    .error(function (e) {
      console.log(e);
    });
};
```

This runs perfectly with the older version of angular, updating it with a more recent version of angular I have the function

```js
let locationListCtrl = ($scope, loc8rData) => {  
  loc8rData
    .then((data) => {
      $scope.data = { locations: data };
    }, (e) => {
      console.log(e);
    });
};
```

This causes an issue with my app and my data is not displaying, and I am getting a [filter:notarray] error, if I remove the filter none of my data is displaying.  The part that I am struggling with is that the only thing that has changed is the promise method and the syntax.  The data returned by the $http method in loc8rData is the same, assigning it to the scope hasn't changed

```js
$scope.data = { locations: data };
```

and the browser sees the returned data the same using both methods, which is returned as an array.

So what am I missing, this is driving me mad.

Thanks

Comment: Can you provide the view part ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deprecated success() function expects 4 arguments:

- data (the body of the response)
- status (the status of the response)
- headers (the headers of the response)
- config (the config object used when sending the request)

The then() function expects a single argument: response. This response object has 4 fields: data, status, headers, config.

So the code should be

```
locatorData
.then(response => {
  $scope.data = { locations: response.data };
}, e => {
  console.log(e);
});
```

Note that I also chose to use `locatorData`, which is much more readable than `loc8rData`.

Comment: Awesome, that's sorted it.  Thank you.